# CentOS 7 PPPoE and Vlan tagging strange behaviour

Tags: networking, centos, modem, authentication, pppoe

I am trying to dial a PPPoE connection from my CentOS 7.7 minimal to my ISP modem (ISP: Unifi, Malaysia).

First I have created a vlan (id: 500) tagged ifcfg file on top on my interface which is eno1.500 as below:

```
IPV6INIT="yes"
DNS2="1.1.1.1"
DNS1="8.8.8.8"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
ONBOOT="yes"
UUID="Same as default ifcfg of eno1"
DEVICE="eno1.500"
VLAN="yes"
```

Then, I have used rp-pppoe to handle the PPPoE setup, which I have also pointed to my vlan tagged interface (eno1.500) with the correct PPPoE username and password.

The result here is what being weird when I found out that my PPPoE connection lasted for only about few seconds. The log as so:

```
Remote Message: Authentication success,Welcome!
PAP authentication succeeded
local IP address xxx
remote IP address: xxx
recv (receivePacket): Network is down
recv (receivePacket): Network is down
Modem hangup
Connect time 0.7 minutes.
Connection terminated.
```

Then recursively:

```
Remote Message: Authentication success,Welcome!
PAP authentication failed.
Modem hangup
Connection terminated.
```

Sometimes the PAP will successfully connect again and failed later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to add the vlan interface with ip command instead (vlan id: 500):

```
$ ip link add link eno1 name eno1.500 type vlan id 500
```

To persist the setting on every reboot, I have added the command under `/etc/rc.local` .

Then, pppoe-setup and point towards the tagged interface eno1.500

Might not be as clean but it works for me for now.